# Trying to add an item into an association (ArrayCollection): Call to undefined method XXXProxy::add

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

When I try to add an item into an assication

```
/**
 * In Note class
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
 * 
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User")
 */
protected $responders;

// in controller: line 80, where error occurs
$note->getResponders()->add($user);
```

I get

> Call to undefined method Proxies...UserBundleEntityUserProxy::add() in ...\Controller\NotesController.php on line 80

Whats wrong?

**UPDATE**

I noticed  its looking under `UserProxy` for the add method, shouldn't it be in the `NoteProxy`? Since responders is in the `Note` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok my question got answered on [Doctrine Google Groups](http://groups.google.com/group/doctrine-user/browse_thread/thread/956ffe1e69260b72/b61df55693426669#b61df55693426669). It was a copy & paste error

```
public function getResponders() {
    return $this->*author*;
}
```